# Unable to Resume Android default music player

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

I am trying to pause any music that is already playing in the Android device that uses default music player. I went over Android doc http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html .  I can pause music when I want, but I am not able to resume the previously paused music after my work is done, although I use am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);

```
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener,
                                         // Use the music stream.
                                         AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                         // Request permanent focus.
                                         AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                mPlayer.start();
        }
```

Once my tone stops I call `am.abandonAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener)` and unable to achieve this.

Comment: There is no single "default music player" in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks. still how do I achieve my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN try AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT.